# Delay PC lock after screen turn off

Tags: windows-10

I've seen 8 questions relative to this and none are about windows 10 subversion 1607.

I want to configure my laptop PC so that, while on battery, it turns off the screen after 2 minutes and auto-locks at 10 minutes when it enters sleep.

I tried looking at the power options, one by one. I tried using the answers for windows 8.1, here, in superuser and also searching the internet using google.
I wasn't able to find anything that works regarding this.

Comment: Why the negative votes?

Answer (score 0):

For laptops there should be control panel applet called "Power settings". Open that and then click "change when the computer sleeps" on the left.

In there you will want to set turn off the display to 2 minutes and put the computer to sleep at 10.

Then go back to the main power options page. On a laptop you should see on the left a "choose what closing the lid does" option. Follow these instructions to enable the password screen after waking up:

1. Click "Change settings that are currently unavailable"
2. Select "Require a password."
3. Save Changes

If it is already set to Require a password, try disabling, saving the changes and then set again. Some forums users have reported the setting does not always stick.

Reference: 
[Link](http://forums.windowscentral.com/ask-question/373532-why-dont-my-screen-lock-after-sleep.html)

Comment: That didn't work. It still auto-locks after 5 seconds after turning the display off.